# Ruby on Rails : upload file to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Android device to upload file to server by using POST method. But I don't know how to make Rails handle this event. It means, after Android device sends file to server by method POST by the link : `http://localhost/upload_file`, rails server can handle this event, and put this file into database, for example.

I have google and some results that tell me use additional plugin. Does exist any pure method just use rails only ? Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails can handle file uploads pretty easily. Here is the relevant guide that you should read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Here's a small snippet from the guide:

> **5.1 What Gets Uploaded**
>
> The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO. Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may in fact be a StringIO or an instance of File backed by a temporary file. In both cases the object will have an original_filename attribute containing the name the file had on the user’s computer and a content_type attribute containing the MIME type of the uploaded file.